# Magento 2 Ui Component resizeDefaultWidth not working

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, uicomponent

I'm building out an admin ui with the built in components, and i have an `actionsColumn` that i'm using. The label of the said `actionsColumn` is long, and i want the layout to not wrap the words, so i'm using the config that i see all over the core core (i.e. - vendor/magento/module-search/view/adminhtml/ui_component/search_synonyms_grid.xml) to do this:

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Namespace\Ui\Component\Grid\Amazon\Account\Menu\Delete">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">account_id</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Action</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

But no matter what value i place in the `resizeDefaultWidth` node i get the same size in the final layout (i have 107 in there now, as i see this all over core code but any value in there give the same result).

One thing i have noticed, it that on page load, before the content is loaded, the label area is bigger then after the page content is loaded. I know a lot of voodoo is going on there, which is why i think `resizeEnabled` need to be false.

Also the `sortOrder` seems to not be working either. Which might be a default of `actionsColumn` as they are suppose to be at the end of the grid (i'm making the assumption that if i had 3 action column, that the sort order with sort those three).

An ideas out there? Is this a bug in M2? or is there a config that i'm missing here?

Comment: yea im facing the same issue

Comment: I want to do some more testing, but i'm thinking this is a bug. I started looking at the core files, but it gets a little convoluted, and i had to move on. But if i find a solution, i will post it here.

Comment: I see that the `xsi:type` of your `resizeDefaultWidth` is `string`. Make it `number`. I don't think it will make a difference, but try it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can explain the sort order problem.
Took me 2 hours to find it some time ago.
The grids built with ui-components have their settings stored in the table `ui_bookmark`.
Even if you don't change anything in the grid, just by viewing it, you get a record in the table `ui_bookamrk`.
THe grid is rendered based on what the row in this table looks like, merged with the ui component xml.
That's why when you add a new column, you will see it last. Because it first renders what's saved in `ui_bookmark`.
Clear the contents of that table `where user_id = {your admin id}`.
If you are on a dev env, just delete everything from that table.

Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if this fixes your column width problem also.

Comment: I gave this a try, but it's still not responding as expected. I did try setting `resizeDefaultWidth` to both string and number, just in case that might make a difference. After truncating the `ui_bookmark` table, i see that is repopulating with new content, so i don't think i'm on the wrong db, or this is a read/write issue for just my local install. I have also been sure to delete cache and view_preprocessed with each change. Any other ideas?

Comment: I did try to de-bug the JS file where i "think" the resize is happening (*vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/resize.js*) but even placing a `console.log` in the file's `initialize` function doesn't return anything. This file is the only place where `resizeDefaultWidth` shows up (outside of uses in xml). So it's almost like `resize.js` is not getting called at all on the page.

Comment: I haven't had time to dig any deeper into why this still isn't working. When i track it down, i will post here.

Comment: Sorry. Me neither. Will do the same if I track something

Comment: you're a busy man! I think i have a little more free time

Answer (score 1):

even though it's a bit late, here is the way how to use resizeDefaultWidth.

Make sure you added the component `ColumnsResize` : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-columns-resize.html

On the documentation above, you can see this config :

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/resize</item>
                    <item name="rootSelector" xsi:type="string">${ $.columnsProvider }:.admin__data-grid-wrap</item>
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">${ $.name }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
```

Please note that on the rootSelector config, `${ $.columnsProvider }` returns `undefined` for me , and then I had to replace it by `${ $.name }` in order to make it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not working in Magento 2.4. Any other approach?

Comment: It should, it's based from dev doc for 2.4 . I do not have another approach. Feel free to put your snippet.